# Counter MAC Spoofing with Cisco

Tags: configuration, mac, spoofing

I was wondering if someone could help me with the needed cisco commands to configure a switch to only allow certain mac addresses on certain ports. So that one mac adres can only connect to the network through a specific port.

Also how to be able to configure to use port 24 as a trusted port and have all other ports set as untrusted (while still using the above mentioned allowing certain MAC addresses on specific ports)

This would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Dempsey

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using many switch cisco features, something like:

> **port-security**
>
> ```
> set port security 1/1-2 enable            # enable port security
> set port security 1/1-2 port max 5        # allow 5 MAC address
> set port security 1/1-2 violation protect # drop packet beyond 5 MAC address
> ```
>
> **mac access-list**
>
> mac access-list extended ARP_Packet           # creat ARP access-list
>
> permit host X.X.X host Y.Y.Y                  # define action, allow or deny
>
> end
>
> **static MAC**
>
> arpa X.X.X IP

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try it out and let you know ;) Thanks for the information! ;)

Comment: Edit: I've tried to figure it out but I haven't been able to find anything related to the commands you gave regarding port-security. Are these commands accurate?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can refer here: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps646/products_configuration_example09186a0080470c39.shtml